# Read and delete files in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, database-backups

I am trying to read and delete any specific file in sql server .

**Scenario**

When i am trying to publish my database using a `Post Deployment Script` , it automatically takes backup of database in default `Backup` directory . Now i am getting that folder bigger day by day . Now i want to write a sql job that will execute and will delete all bakcup files except last two . Is this possible and also is this appropriate to do in sql . If no then why ?

Comment: @downvoter , if this is a wrong question you must down vote but please care to explain it help peoples to improve for next time

Comment: How is your backup files named? By which criteria you sort your files and decide which are first two?

Comment: filesnames are like this : databasename_datetime.bak

Comment: look at my answer, maybe it will help you

Answer (score 1):

You can create SQL Job to delete file from file system.

First of all, you must have SQL Agent service started.

Next step is creating powershell script for deleting desired files. Place script on, by example, `D:\Test\` folder and give a name to script like **DeleteFile.ps1**. Edit script, and write next code:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem D:\Test *.txt | Select Name, CreationTime, FullName | Sort CreationTime

for ($i=0; $i -lt ($files.Count -2); $i++) {
    Remove-Item $files[$i].FullName
}
```

and then save and close editor.

Then, under **SQL Agent** tree, right click on **Jobs** folder and choose **New Job**. On dialog window, in **General** tab, give a name to job, and then on left side of the window, choose **Steps**, and then **New**.

On new dialog window, in section **Type**, choose **Operating system (CmdExec)**. In field **Command**, just call powershell script you create for deleting desired files:

```
D:\Test\DeleteFile.ps1
```

and click **OK** to create job.

When done, to test deleting files, right click on created job, and then choose **Start Job as Step** option.

**NOTE**

It is suggested to test all this work on some test machine before put it in production. Files which I delete is `.txt` files, but you just need to change code to map `.bak` files. Of course, you can change location of files.

Answer (score 0):

> Now i am getting that folder bigger day by day . Now i want to write a sql job that will execute and will delete all bakcup files except last two

The default option when you take backup is to append the current backup file with previous one. The option is `(NOINIT).` Please see [backup documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186865.aspx) What you have to do is add `INIT` option while taking the backup, this would overwrite the previous backup.

If your scenario is such that you just want to remove old backup files this can be done by writing custom script. Fortunately you have [Ola Hallengren script](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-backup.html) for this. I strongly suggest you to first read FAQ's and excample. reading examples wll make things clear for you as to how the script works